# How to search for a word part without capuring the full word

Tags: regex

**A bit of context**

I'm renaming all instances of a "config" variable to "configuration".

In order to validate that I renamed every existing instance of the variable, I use the Find In Files feature of Visual Studio. I search for "config" and it returns me results for variables named either "config" and "configuration", since a search for config matches both. However, I'm only interested in seeing the "config" ones (which need renaming), not the "configuration" ones (which are correctly named).

It is actually a problem since it's a pain to scroll through hundreds of irrelevant search results.

**Here comes the regex**

Therefore, I'm looking to use a regex in the search to solve my problem. A regex that would match anything containing config, except if it contains configuration. For example, someConfigVariable should be a match and someConfigurationVariable should not be.

Comment: You can use negative lookahead `config(?!uration)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use lookaheads: `config(?!uration)`.

Comment: It would fail if there are other words like `configurable` `configured` etc

Comment: @exexzian Well, OP didn’t mention those cases…

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
(Config)(?!uration)
```

[Working Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eY4rU2/1)

It captures the word `Config` which can be accessed using `$1` for substitution.

Uses [Group Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2k3te2cs(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
 \bconfiguration\b|\bconfig\b
```

Try this.Replace by `configuration`.See demo.Just capture `configuration` as well.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/19